# Create bots on my javascript app that sends data to other app which runs only on InternetExplorer8-9 browsers

Tags: javascript, node.js, internet-explorer, bots, ie8-compatibility-mode

I'm a newbie to javascript and struggling with problems I found on planning my new app(A). Basically, one feature of my app(A) is a bot that makes login, fill some forms and receives html data from another application(B) which runs only on IE8-9 browsers and requires local authentication with tokens. The problem is that my app(A) runs Angular, bootstrap and other packages that IE8-9 browsers woudn't load in satisfactory way. The possible solutions I thought were:
1-Change all my application(A) to some library that IE8-9 browser can run and loose some features.
2- Inside my app(A) somehow emulate a hidden IE8-9 browser to run app(B) and so the bots could work.
3-Find some resource that makes all these bots and features to run on IE8-9 browser.
Which advices would you give me for this problem? Thanks!